Attempting to connect with WinSCP to SFTP but getting error: Too many parameters for command 'open'
Tried many things so now I'm hoping one of you can spot my issue.
Getting error

Too many parameters for command 'open'.

Here is the WinSCP syntax I am using:
option batch abort
option confirm off 
open sftp://User Name:Password@1.10.100.1000/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 4096 bla:bla:bla"

cd /Folder

lcd "X:\Folder"

get *.pdf

bye

Also tried other formatting techniques with double wrapping with quotes and separating the get into another bat file.  Also tried get vs mget with no luck.

If your username (or any parameter of any command) really contains a space, then you need to quote it like:
open "sftp://User Name:Password@1.10.100.1000/" -hostkey="ssh-rsa 4096 bla:bla:bla"

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes

Other questions with the same error message, but different problem:

WinSCP command line - Too many parameters for command 'open' when using -rawtransfersettings switch
WinSCP "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error
Getting "Too many parameters for command", when calling WinSCP command-line from VBA

